# Galasoft RelayCommand not firing

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, mvvm-light, relaycommand

I am using the MVVM Light framework to build a SL4 application. My simple app is composed primarily by a single main view (shellView), which is divided into multiple UserControls. They are just a convenient separation of the UI, therefore they don't have their own ViewModel.

The ShellView contains a Keypad (custom usercontrol) that contains multiple KeypadButtons (custom usercontrols).

I am quite sure (because I've checked) that the DataContext is set properly and it is used by all usercontrols in the hierarchy. (ShellView's Datacontext is ShellViewModel, Keypad's DataContext is ShellViewModel, etc.).

In the ShellViewModel I have a ICommand (RelayCommand) that is named "ProcessKey".

In the Keypad control, I have something like:

```
<controls:KeypadButton x:Name="testBtn" Text="Hello">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                <GalaSoft_MvvmLight_Command:EventToCommand Command="{Binding PressStandardKeyCommand}" />
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</controls:KeypadButton>
```

The KeypadButton is basically a Grid that contains a Button. The MouseLeftButtonUp event is caught and a custom "Click" event is fired. Let me show you some code to explain easily what I am doing:

```
public partial class KeypadButton : UserControl
{
    public delegate void KeypadButtonClickHandler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e);
    public event KeypadButtonClickHandler Click;

public KeypadButton()
{
        // Required to initialize variables
    InitializeComponent();
}

    private void innerButton_Click(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Click != null)
            Click(sender, new KeypadButtonEventArgs());
    }
}

public class KeypadButtonEventArgs : RoutedEventArgs
{
    public string test { get; set; }
}
```

Now, if I set a breakpoint to the body of innerButton_Click, I can see the Click is properly caught and it contains points to the RelayCommand. However, nothing happens: "Click(sender, new KeypadButtonEventArgs());" is executed but nothing more.

Why is this behaving so? Shouldnt execute the target function that is defined in the RelayCommand? Is maybe a scope-related issue?

Thanks in advance,
Cheers,
Gianluca.

Answer (score 1):

As noted by other comments, this is probably related to the `Click` event not being a `RoutedEvent`.

As a quick hack you might be able to use `MouseLeftButtonDown` instead of the `Click` event on your `UserControl`.

```
<!-- Kinda Hacky Click Interception -->
<controls:KeypadButton x:Name="testBtn" Text="Hello">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonDown">
                <GalaSoft_MvvmLight_Command:EventToCommand Command="{Binding PressStandardKeyCommand}" />
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</controls:KeypadButton>
```

Another option you could consider is inheriting from `Button` instead of `UserControl`.  Silverlight Show has an [article about inheriting from a TextBox](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Create-a-Custom-Control-Inheriting-from-TextBox.aspx) that probably is relevant for this.

Comment: +1, especially the bit about inheriting from what you need, not all the way down from Control/UserControl - unless absolutely needed.

Comment: @Alex: thank you but I believe that we are missing the point here. Also, I've tried already with MouseLeftButtonUp (which should be the same) and it did not work. The KeypadButton's event is generated and I can subscribe to it programmatically, from the code. The problem appears to be EventTrigger not being able to catch the generated event. I posted here the question to understand if custom events in silvelright usercontrols need to be implemented in some specific way in order to work in XAML and with the EventToCommand.

Answer (score 0):

Routed events should be defined like this ([see documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806.aspx)):

```
public static readonly RoutedEvent TapEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent(
    "Tap", RoutingStrategy.Bubble, typeof(RoutedEventHandler), typeof(MyButtonSimple));

// Provide CLR accessors for the event
public event RoutedEventHandler Tap
{
        add { AddHandler(TapEvent, value); } 
        remove { RemoveHandler(TapEvent, value); }
}
```

Comment: As said in my post, I am using SL4. As far as I know there is no EventManager in there. Am I wrong?

Comment: I've tried to declare my custom event handler as a RoutedEventHandler, but still I have the same problem. I can see the Click event has a EventTriggerBase instance in it, but when it should actually be invoked, nothing happens. Any help would be really appreciated! Thank you everybody!

Comment: Sorry, wasn't aware that you were using SL (need to read better next time). According to this article (http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Routed-Events-in-Silverlight.aspx), custom routed events are not supported in SL.

Comment: Why don't you implement the ICommand on the control? Then the problem would be solved.